Why edditing value using pointer, that is class private field, requires declaring additional variable?
I have defined three simple files:
main.cpp
#include <iostream>
#include "EventHandler.h"

int main(int argc, char *argv[])
{
    bool myFlag = true;

    EventHandler eventHandler = EventHandler(&myFlag);

    std::cout << myFlag << std::endl;
    eventHandler.update();
    std::cout << myFlag << std::endl;
}

EventHandler.h
#pragma once

class EventHandler
{
private:
    bool *myFlag;

public:
    EventHandler(bool *myFlag);

    void update();
};

EventHandler.cpp
#include "EventHandler.h"
#include <iostream>

EventHandler::EventHandler(bool *myFlag)
{
    this->myFlag= myFlag;
}

void EventHandler::update()
{
    this->myFlag = false;
    // bool *tempVar = this->myFlag;
    // *tempVar  = false;

    std::cout << *this->myFlag << std::endl;
};


And what I want to do is to modify value of myFlag using update function from EventHandler class. I managed to achieve this by replacing:
this->myFlag = false;

with:
bool *tempVar  = this->myFlag;
*tempVar  = false;

But this solution seems counterintuitive to me, hence the question wether (and if so then how) it is possible to achieve the same result without the need of declaring the "temporary variable" and perhaps dare I say in one line only?

bool *myFlag; should be a bool myFlag; IMHO.  There is no reason why you need to provide the bool, the class is more than capable to handling it itself.

*myFlag = false

You need to dereference not just this but also this->myFlag when assigning.
void EventHandler::update()
{
    *this->myFlag = false;

    std::cout << *this->myFlag << std::endl;
};

But you don't need this at all, explicitly. There is no local myFlag variable to disambiguate from.
void EventHandler::update()
{
    *myFlag = false;

    std::cout << *myFlag << std::endl;
};

